# Why IE10 shows something totally different

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using CSS/JQuery along with image sprite to give it a image fade swap effect.

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.otherbutton').append('<img class="hover" />').each(function () {
            var $span = $('> img.hover', this).css('opacity', 0);
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $span.stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
            }, function () {
        $span.stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.otherbutton {
    clear: both;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/searchButton.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}   
.otherbutton img.hover {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/searchButton.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="otherbutton"></span>
```

In FF, the image is displayed correctly but for IE 8,9,10 the hover image is displayed as NOT FOUND. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Background positions require two values.

Comment: @Diodeus: It supports 1-4 values.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: IE is the only browser with an issue

Comment: Why are you using an image tag and applying a background-image to it? Why are you not just adding the source to that image? And are you sure the png is really a png?

Comment: All I am trying to do is... Have an image and when the user hover overs it it fade away to another image and when the user hovers away from it it fades back to the original image which works on all browsers. I am just not getting anywhere with it.

Comment: Yes it is a PNG because the default image shows up but when hovered over, it has the image not found icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure CSS based alternative that should work in most modern browsers (but not IE9 and below):

HTML:

```
<span>
    <img src="/path/to/hover/image" />
    <img src="/path/to/image" />
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

span img {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

span img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kn9FK/4/

Comment: The [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) CSS3 property is not supported in IE9 and below, and the OP stated they are testing in IE8-10.

Comment: My point is that this answer is likely not going to work for OP.

Comment: I was not trying to "stroke my ego". My apologies that my attempt to be helpful has irritated you.

Comment: Intentions can be hard to decipher sometimes through the internet. I have edited my answer to note that this doesn't work in IE9 and below to clarify for those interested in this solution.

Comment: I also used the CSS and used `visibility: visible;` and `opacity: 1` in the `img:hover:after` style and it's working correctly.